# gcloud command to change instance type?

Tags: google-compute-engine, gcloud

Looking for a quick gcloud example to change an instances type. For example I would like to change an instance from 32vcpus/64GB RAM to 2vcpus/4GB RAM. I know how to do it in the web interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the machine type to your requirements by using the command:

```
gcloud compute instances set-machine-type <instance-name> --custom-cpu=2  
--custom-memory=4 --zone <instance-zone>
```

You can find further information and instructions in the following [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/set-machine-type).